# How to make a multi-level module hierarchy with (or without) Oasis

Tags: module, ocaml, oasis

Suppose I have a set of modules each of which being rather "bushy" with submodules.

```
M1.X        M2.X        M3.X
M1.Y        M2.Y        M3.Y
M1.Z        M2.Z        M3.Z
M1.W        M2.W        M3.W
M1.Q        M2.Q        M3.Q
M1.P        M2.P        M3.P
```

Moreover, I'd like each of these bushes to sit under one master module.

```
Home.M1
Home.M2
Home.M3
```

Now, it's easy to structure the project directory for each of `M1`, `M2`, and `M3` using Oasis' `Pack:` option. In particular, what I like and am trying to solve for is (a) the ability to lay out my files in the standard `.ml`/`.mli` format and (b) having `ocamldoc` produce properly linked documentation.

But since I'd like to distribute each of `M1`, `M2`, and `M3` in the same library under a common module hierarchy I cannot use `Pack:` and am instead forced to throw the whole damn thing into a single file in order to (a) not accidentally clobber the global namespace, (b) not accidentally proliferate modules all over the `Home.` namespace which are not intended to be used directly, and (c) not ruin ocamldoc linking.

*So my question is, subject to the goals suggested above, how can I use Oasis to create a package with hierarchical modules of this form?*

Some additional constraints include:

- It is no accident that the modules under the `M1.`, `M2.`, and `M3.` namespaces conflict---this occurs in the genuine situation as well!
- The modules in the `M2.` and `M3.` namespace depend upon the modules in the `M1.` namespace.

My preference would be able to arrive at a solution which also allows a sensible file layout, e.g.

```
src -+
     +-- m1 -+
     |       +-- x.ml
     |       +-- x.mli
     |       +-- y.ml
     |       +-- y.mli
     |       +-- z.ml
     |       +-- z.mli
     |       |
     |       ...
     |
     |
     +-- m2 -+
     |       +-- x.ml
     |       +-- x.mli
     |       +-- y.ml
     |       +-- y.mli
     |       +-- z.ml
     |       +-- z.mli
     |       |
     |       ...
     |
     |
     +-- m3 -+
             +-- x.ml
             +-- x.mli
             +-- y.ml
             +-- y.mli
             +-- z.ml
             +-- z.mli
             |
             ...
```

It may also be possible that this is impossible with Oasis. In such a case, suggestions as to how to use other build tools are acceptable and welcome. Assume I have very little understanding of the other tools... because it's probably true!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### With oasis

The `pack` in `oasis` is a little bit broken, as it clobbers the namespace by including all paths into the search path. There is a long-living accepted bug request, but things are still where they are. But, if it worked correctly, it can help you, since it will create a library namespaces, allowing you to have modules with the same name in different folder. But, it doesn't work, so we should forget about it.

The approach we have taken in [BAP](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap) project was to mangle all module names with ugly `bap_subproject_` prefix, that protects us from conflicts with our own modules, as well as from conflicts coming from external libraries. For each `bap_subproject` we have a folder with all implementation modules with mangled names and one umbrella module to rule them all. This module is stored in file `bap_subproject.ml` where it defines aliases for all modules and types that it is going to export. Usually it contains entries like:

```
module X = Bap_subproject_x
```

There is also a big `Bap` project, that unites all sublibraries under one namespace `Bap.Std`, and reexports everything it needs, so that after one `open Bap.Std` you have and access to `Insn` module that is defined in `bap_disasm/bap_disasm_insn.ml[i]`

### Without oasis

Disclaimer: this solution may still work with oasis if you extend it with plugin.

We've used this approach in one project, that is unfortunately closed source, so I can't provide a link. Each subproject lives in its own subfolder, within it own namespace (we have had `parser` module in each subfolder, without any clobber). For each subproject there is an `mlpack` file, in the `top` folder:

```
 root +
      |
      +-- expr.mlpack
      +-- expr -+
                |
                +- lexer.*
                +- parser.*
                +- ast.*
                +- ...
      +-- cameo.mlpack
      +-- cameo-+
                |
                +- lexer.*
                +- parser.*
                +- ast.*
                +- ...
```

The contents of the `expr.mlpack` is:

```
   expr/Lexer
   expr/Parser
   expr/Ast
   ...
```

`ocamlbuild` sees this `expr.mlpack` as a standalone module that has `Lexer`, `Parser`, etc submodules defined in it (and accessible as, e.g., `Expr.Lexer`). And there is no conflicts with a sibling project that also has `Lexer`, as well as no conflicts with `ocaml-libs` or any other external `Lexer`, since the `expr` folder is actually never included into the search path.

If you need to add yet another layer to your system, like a pack for packs, then you have three choices:

1. use the same approach recursively, i.e., create yet another super folder, that has `mlpack` or `mllib` files pointing to a child folder.
2. just add `big.mlpack` that references all toplevel `mlpack`'ed modules
3. create `big.ml` that reintroduces all modules.

Last two approaches requires top-level packed modules to have different names of course. But usually this is fair enough.

Comment: I've seen that solution in a few places—I think `Core` is another example. It's clearly workable, but it's also kind of repulsive to do manual name mangling and to drop that module refuse into more primary namespaces. I'd run with it, but I'm really hoping that there are other solutions—even if they require dropping Oasis.

Comment: Without oasis it is doable, if I understand your requirements correctly. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The explicit `mlpack` solution is really promising! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: As a further question (which maybe I'll just open at the top level again) how can I write module-level documentation for a module created only through an `mlpack` file?

Comment: I would create yet another umbrella module that again reexports modules from `mlpack`, but with comments.