# Organizing OCaml projects: files and modules

Tags: ocaml

I would like to restructure my project from a flat file/module hierarchy into a more nested one. Here is what I have now:

```
.                    # Modules:
├── fruit_apple.ml   # Fruit_apple
├── fruit_lemon.ml   # Fruit_lemon
├── pie_apple.ml     # Pie_apple
└── pie_lemon.ml     # Pie_lemon
```

Here is what I want to get:

```
.                    # Modules:
├── fruit
│   ├── apple.ml     # Fruit.Apple
│   └── lemon.ml     # Fruit.Lemon
└── pie
    ├── apple.ml     # Pie.Apple
    └── lemon.ml     # Pie.Lemon
```

OCaml has automatic mapping from file name to module name, but it doesn't seem to have one for directories and nested files.

I could have a `pie.ml` and `fruit.ml` file where I include the necessary submodules:

```
(* pie.ml *)

module Apple = struct
  include Apple
end

module Lemon = struct
  include Lemon
end
```

But I don't know how to resolve the ambiguity between `pie/apple.ml` and `fruit/apple.ml`.

I tried to study [Core](https://github.com/janestreet/core) library, which has `Core` namespace with nested modules `Core.Bool`, `Core.Bag` and so on, but I couldn't find a `core.ml` file there which I would assume integrates all the submodules.

Comment: core is packed with `-pack` option, so that every module automatically enveloped in `Core` module. What you're looking is `std.ml`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a multi-level module hierarchy with (or without) Oasis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722704/how-to-make-a-multi-level-module-hierarchy-with-or-without-oasis)

Answer (score 2):

Since the introduction of module aliases in OCaml the preferred way to deal with this is to:

- Develop modules in unambiguously identified modules
  with globally unique names.
- If you wish, prepare a special module simulating a namespace,
  which might be nicer to the user than a flat collection of modules.

So, additionally to your current module definitions, you can add

```
(* Fruit.ml *)
module Apple = Fruit_Apple
module Lemon = Fruit_Lemon

(* Pie.ml *)
module Apple = Pie_Apple
module Lemon = Pie_Lemon
```

If appropriate, you should consider adding a global prefix identifying your library, so that other libraries can provide `Fruit` and `Pie` modules without competing with yours.